# How to set delayed replication with MariaDB 10.0.11

Tags: mariadb

Is it possible to set delayed replication on MariaDB 10.0.11?
I tried the following command:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_DELAY = N;
```

It returns the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'MASTER_DELAY = 259200' at line 1

If not supported, are there any other recommended solutions to protect against user mistakes on the master & allow a DBA to roll back a delayed slave to the time just before the disaster ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

`MASTER_DELAY` is not available in MariaDB 10.0.x. You may want to try Percona's pt-slave-delay.

Usage:

```
pt-slave-delay [OPTION...] SLAVE-HOST [MASTER-HOST]
```

Example: To hold slavehost one minute behind its master for ten minutes:

```
pt-slave-delay --delay 1m --interval 15s --run-time 10m slavehost
```

Source: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-slave-delay.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a JIRA ticket for MariaDB to implement this feature https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-7145

Edit: it is now implemented in 10.2 (soon to be GA)